# How do I specify a user-assigned managed identity in Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-managed-identity

Setting a system-assigned managed identity in Azure API management is easy - just flip the toggle in the blade, or use the following code snippet in your ARM template

```
"identity" : {
    "type" : "SystemAssigned"
}
```

However, I have several instances of API management, and I want them all to use the same identity, for which the normal Azure solution is a user-assigned MSI.

However, I can't find anything that suggests how to add a reference to a user-assigned MSI to my Azure APIM instance or to set it up in the portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Assigned Managed Identity for API management is not yet supported

[image]

If you want to read more or check supported service feel free to check my article on Managed Identities https://marczak.io/posts/2019/07/securing-websites-with-msi/

Comment: The feature is being worked on right now, so expect it soon.

Comment: I wonder why my response is being downvoted even if it answers OP question.

Comment: It seems that is supported for App Services. However, I cant make it work. I'm using ARM template to provision an App Service and link it to an existing user-assigned managed identity but in the best case the App Service is provisioned but without any identities linked.

Comment: @MauriR Refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet#using-the-rest-protocol) on how to choose a user-assigned identity for an App Service. Note that you _must_ provide one or more of the `client_id`, `principal_id` or `mi_res_id` query parameters or else the system assigned identity is used.

Answer (score 2):

This is currently in Preview.
Here is the link to the official documentation:

[Services that support managed identities for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/services-support-managed-identities#azure-api-management)

Comment: Update: It is now implemented and in "Preview", but having tried it out, it is not being made use of when e.g. retrieving certificate from a Key Vault, in which context only the System Assigned identity is used.